# how to add bottom TextFormField in flutter like send comment buttton

Tags: flutter, comments

```
child: Row(
    children: [
      // First child is enter comment text input
      TextFormField(
        controller: commentController,
        autocorrect: false,
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Some Text",
          hintText: "Write a comment",
          labelStyle:
          TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
          fillColor: Colors.blue,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            // borderRadius:`your text`
            //     BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero(5.0)),
              borderSide:
              BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent)),
        ),
      ),
      // Second child is button
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        iconSize: 20.0,
        onPressed: () {

        },
      )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and use [`suffixIcon`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/suffixIcon.html) widget is best for your design

```
TextFormField(
  autocorrect: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.send),
      iconSize: 20.0,
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    labelText: "Some Text",
    hintText: "Write a comment",
    fillColor: Colors.blue,
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Your code result-> [image]

My above code result-> [image]